# Chrome does not load css map files?

Tags: css, google-chrome, less

I have a small project.

```
index.html  
styles/  
--common.less
```

The content of index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/common.css">
<div>Hello</div>
```

The content of common.less:

```
div {color: red;}
```

Command I used to compile less file:

```
balabala>lessc styles\common.less > styles\common.css --source-map=styles\common.css.map --source-map-basepath=styles
```

Generated common.css:

```
div {
  color: red;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles/common.css.map */
```

But chrome does not load that map file (I have checked the network panel) . I have made sure that I have enabled css source maps in dev tools.

### EDIT:

Actually chrome is loading these map files, but it just doesn't show them in the network panel. I checked the output of `http-server`, and found that chrome is requesting 'wrong' path. CSS should give the absolute path of sourcemap file, while sourcemap file should give the relative path of less file.

Comment: check you path once.

Comment: Which path?@PardeepJain

Comment: also try using deleting this line `/*# sourceMappingURL=common.css.map */` from `common.css` file